# Hosting Ethereum on Digital Ocean

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, server-side, hosting, digitalocean

I am not quite sure whether this is right place to ask this question but let's carry it forward. I wanted to host `Ethereum on Digital ocean`. Has anyone ever tried that? Any `HowTos` on hosting ethereum on Digital ocean. I am more concerned about whether will I be able to access Mist(Ethereum Wallet) from there in same manner as I am using it on my local machine.

Comment: Note: I tried asking the same question on Digital Ocean community but didn't get any help. Probably our community can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on running a full client on a VPS from digital ocean you can access it using [ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH) and just copy the client and/or files such as accounts and contracts:

```
$ scp -r directoryWithEthClientAndFiles/ VPSHostName@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/to/remote/directory
$ ssh VPSHostName@xx.xx.xx.xx
# Enter password if user/pass authentication is enabled
$ cd /path/to/remote/directory
# Launch geth
$ ./geth
```

To run a GUI app such as Mist you need to run:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
```

on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks. So,Does Digital ocean provides installation and access of GUIs on linux or it provides only shell? Like Mist is a GUI app and can I access any GUI apps just like I do it on my local machine.

Comment: It depends on the service (you can get a full list of them here: https://www.digitalocean.com/products/ ). You can access GUI resources from shell access.

Comment: Thanks for response. Now I have a digital ocean VPS, I don't want to run geth on it, I want to run Mist on it,. I downloaded Ethereum wallet there but running `./Ethereum-Wallet` doesn't do anything. Probably `digital ocean` doesn't provide access to GUI environment. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Did you export the display environment variable?

Comment: I followed [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/remotely-access-graphical-desktop-of-ubuntu-14-04-server/) to access GUI of my droplet. and It worked well. But when I tried running Mist there , it didn't opened , while running from command line `killed` was displayed after some time on konsole. Any idea why the process was killed? TIA

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is pretty possible. On the other hand to keep your money on platform like Digital Ocean doesn`t look as a good practice. Platforms with a strong identity management like AWS, Azure, Google Cloud are more preferable.